# how to post large data from jquery ajax to .NET WCF service

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, wcf

im working on capturing the page data and mouse movements using js and jquery in my client application. i captured all below mentioned data without any problem. I need to send my client application data to WCF service application for process. normally less data means aroung 4000 bytes means without having any problem, data has been sent. but if i send more than that means, its shows error of

> 400 bad request
>
> data is exceeding the limit of the page of  4000 bytes.
> .

im using mexhttpbinding endpoint, beacuse of we are used to send data to cross domain.

Please provide suggestions to overcome this issue.
[NOTE] Im sending json data

Comment: You can set length of data in web.config. Refer this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config

Answer (score 0):

```
In Web.config  , 
Add : <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="ApiQuotaBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="300971520" maxBufferPoolSize="300971520" maxBufferSize="300971520" closeTimeout="00:50:00" openTimeout="00:50:00" receiveTimeout="00:50:00" sendTimeout="00:50:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="402" maxStringContentLength="300971520" maxArrayLength="300971520" maxBytesPerRead="300971520"/>
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>   </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: im using mexHttpBinding. its doesn't takes these configurations. what should i do? ><endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>